# Merging objects based on their values

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, javascript-objects, merging-data

I have an array of objects and I’m trying to combine them together into a single object, based on their values.

For example, if I have this array:

```
const arr = [
    {mo: true, tu: true, we: {...another object}, th: true, fr: true, sa: {...aDifferentObject}, su: true},
    {mo: {...aThirdObject}, tu: true, we: true, th: true, fr: true, sa: true, su: true}
```

I would then want to return:

```
console.dir(combineObjects(arr))
// {mo: {...aThirdObject}, tu: true, we: {...another object}, th: true, fr: true, sa: {...aDifferentObject}, su: true},
```

With that, I also need to decide on what to do when multiples keys of the same name have objects in them.

I've tried various methods like `arr.reduce()` and `Object.keys(arr[0]).forEach()` but `reduce()` returns an array and `Object.keys().forEach()` gets really messy really quickly.

Is there an easier way to do this? I feel like I must be overthinking it.

[EDIT: The actual input and expected output were requested in the comments]

```
// Input
[{fr:{ 
    beginWork: ['08', '00'],
    end: ['23', '59'],
    endWork: ['16', '15'],
    start: ['00', '00'],
    },
    mo: true,
    sa: true,
    su: {
        beginWork: ['08', '00']
        end: ['23', '59']
        endWork: ['16', '15']
        start: ['00', '00']
    },
    th: true,
    tu: {
        beginWork: ['08', '00']
        end: ['23', '59']
        endWork: ['16', '15']
        start: ['00', '00']
    },
    we: true,
},
{
    fr: {
        end: ['13', '00']
        start: ['00', '00']
    },
    mo: {
        end: ['13', '00']
        start: ['00', '00']
    },
    sa: {
        end: ['13', '00']
        start: ['00', '00']
    },
    su: {
        end: ['13', '00']
        start: ['00', '00']
    },
    th: {
        end: ['13', '00']
        start: ['00', '00']
    },
    tu: {
        end: ['13', '00']
        start: ['00', '00']
    },
    we: true
}]
```

```
// Expected output
{
    fr:{ 
        beginWork: ['08', '00'],
        end: ['23', '59'],
        endWork: ['16', '15'],
        start: ['00', '00'],
    },
    mo: {
        end: ['13', '00']
        start: ['00', '00']
    },
    sa: {
        end: ['13', '00']
        start: ['00', '00']
    },
    su: {
        beginWork: ['08', '00']
        end: ['23', '59']
        endWork: ['16', '15']
        start: ['00', '00']
    },
    th: {
        end: ['13', '00']
        start: ['00', '00']
    },
    tu: {
        beginWork: ['08', '00']
        end: ['23', '59']
        endWork: ['16', '15']
        start: ['00', '00']
    },
    we: true,
},
```

Please and thank you in advance :)

I hope you all have a great day!

Comment: can you show actual INPUT and  expected OUTPUT?

Comment: @shutsman It has been added :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach,

```
const arr = [
    {mo: true, tu: true, we: { test : 1}, th: true, fr: true, sa: { test: 2 }, su: true},
    {mo: {test : 3}, tu: true, we: true, th: true, fr: true, sa: true, su: true}
    ];
let result = arr[0];
arr.forEach(element => {
    Object.keys(result).forEach(key => {
        if(typeof(element[key]) != 'boolean'){
            result[key] = element[key];
        }
    });
});   
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through reduce and add conditions on the match. You can checkout the below example. Here you can write custom logic for `shouldMap`
based on ur need

```js
const combine = (...args) => {
  let shouldMap = () => true;
  if (typeof args[args.length - 1] === "function") {
    shouldMap = args.pop();
  }
  return args.reduce((acc, item) => {
    Object.entries(item).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      if (shouldMap(key, acc, value)) acc[key] = value;
    });
    return acc;
  }, {});
};


const aDifferentObject = { 1: 1 };
const aThirdObject = { 2: 2 };
const arr = [
  {
    mo: true,
    tu: true,
    we: {},
    th: true,
    fr: true,
    sa: { ...aDifferentObject },
    su: true,
  },
  {
    mo: { ...aThirdObject },
    tu: true,
    we: true,
    th: true,
    fr: true,
    sa: true,
    su: true,
  },
];


console.log(
  combine(
    ...arr,
    (key, acc, value) =>
      !(typeof value !== "object" && typeof acc[key] === "object")
  )
);
```

**A simplified version of combine:**

```
const combine = (...args) => {
  let shouldMap = () => true;
  if (typeof args[args.length - 1] === "function") {
    shouldMap = args.pop();
  }
  let result = {};
  for (let item of args) {
    for (let key in item) {
      if (shouldMap(key, result, item[key])) result[key] = item[key];
    }
  }
  return result;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to combine your array elements into one object.

As we enumerate each element in the array, we'll replace any property of the result *if* it is not an object.

```js
const input = [{fr:{ beginWork: ['08', '00'], end: ['23', '59'], endWork: ['16', '15'], start: ['00', '00'], }, mo: true, sa: true, su: { beginWork: ['08', '00'], end: ['23', '59'], endWork: ['16', '15'], start: ['00', '00'] }, th: true, tu: { beginWork: ['08', '00'], end: ['23', '59'], endWork: ['16', '15'], start: ['00', '00'] }, we: true, }, { fr: { end: ['13', '00'], start: ['00', '00'] }, mo: { end: ['13', '00'], start: ['00', '00'] }, sa: { end: ['13', '00'], start: ['00', '00'] }, su: { end: ['13', '00'], start: ['00', '00'] }, th: { end: ['13', '00'], start: ['00', '00'] }, tu: { end: ['13', '00'], start: ['00', '00'] }, we: true }]

function isObject(input) { 
    return input && (typeof(input) === 'object');
}

const result = input.reduce((acc, el) => { 
   return Object.keys(el).reduce((acc, key) => {
       // Don't replace if it's an object...
       return isObject(acc[key]) ? acc: { ...acc, [key]: el[key] };
   }, acc)
}, {});

console.log('Result:', result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```